# How do I get the selected option value as a string in PHP?

Tags: php, html

My aim is to get the selected item from the drop down and covert it to type string. After conversion, am comparing the result with another string and then use if() statement to execute some code. But the conversion does not seem to work because the program only execute else() statement. How can I do this? somebody help Please.

Below is my html and php code.

```
          <select name="p_category">
              <option selected disabled >-- select --</option>
              <option value="computers">Computer</option>
              <option value="phones" >Phone</option>
              <option value="accessories">Accessory</option>
              <option value="general">Display</option>
              
            </select>
<?php 
  $getCategory = $_POST['p_category'];
  $value = strval($getCategory);
  $comps = "computer";
  
  if($value == $comps){
    echo "<script>alert('Equal')</script>";
  }else{
    echo "<script>alert('Not equal')</script>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: You have `"computer"` and the option value is `"computers"`

Comment: Try to double-check your work more carefully in future.